how can I adjust my segment tree for this task?
Can't solve that problem.
I built a tree of sum and maximum element segments with mass updates. I also used the technique of pushing elements deep down the tree to sort the operations by time.
I tried a lot of variations of segment tree, but my decision always exceeds the memory limits. I lost a lot of time for optimizing my code. Here my code:
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define all(x) (x).begin(), (x).end()
#define sz(x) (x).size()
#define int long long

int n;

struct Node {
    int mx;
    int sm;
    int on;
    int d;
};

struct Tree {
    vector<Node> tree;
    int size = 1;

    void init(int n) {
        while (size < n) size *= 2;
        tree.assign(2 * size - 1, { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    }

    void propagate(int x, int tl, int tr) {
        if (tr - tl == 1 || !tree[x].on) {
            return;
        }

        tree[2 * x + 1].sm = (tr - tl) / 2 * tree[x].d;
        tree[2 * x + 2].sm = (tr - tl) / 2 * tree[x].d;

        tree[2 * x + 1].mx = (tr - tl) / 2 * tree[x].d;
        tree[2 * x + 2].mx = (tr - tl) / 2 * tree[x].d;

        tree[2 * x + 1].on = 1;
        tree[2 * x + 2].on = 1;

        tree[2 * x + 1].d = tree[x].d;
        tree[2 * x + 2].d = tree[x].d;

        tree[x].on = 0;
        tree[x].d = 0;
    }

    void update(int x, int tl, int tr, int l, int r, int d) {
        propagate(x, tl, tr);
        if (l >= tr || r <= tl) {
            return;
        }
        if (l <= tl && r >= tr) {
            tree[x].d = d;
            tree[x].on = 1;
            tree[x].sm = tree[x].mx = (tr - tl) * d;
            return;
        }
        int mid = (tl + tr) / 2;

        update(2 * x + 1, tl, mid, l, r, d);
        update(2 * x + 2, mid, tr, l, r, d);

        tree[x].sm = tree[2 * x + 1].sm + tree[2 * x + 2].sm;
        tree[x].mx = max(tree[2 * x + 1].mx, tree[2 * x + 1].sm + tree[2 * x + 2].mx);
    }

    void update(int l, int r, int d) {
        update(0, 0, size, l, r, d);
    }

    int query(int x, int tl, int tr, int h) {
        propagate(x, tl, tr);
        if (tr - tl == 1) {
            if (tree[x].mx > h) {
                return tl;
            }
            else {
                return tr;
            }
        }
        int mid = (tl + tr) / 2;
        if (tree[2 * x + 1].mx > h) {
            return query(2 * x + 1, tl, mid, h);
        }
        else {
            return query(2 * x + 2, mid, tr, h - tree[2 * x + 1].sm);
        }
    }

    int query(int h) {
        return query(0, 0, size, h);
    }
};

void solve() {
    cin >> n;

    Tree T; T.init(n);

    char query;

    while (cin >> query && query != 'E') {
        if (query == 'I') {
            int a, b, d; cin >> a >> b >> d;
            a--;
            T.update(a, b, d);
        }
        else {
            int h; cin >> h;
            cout << min(n, T.query(h)) << '\n';
        }
    }
}

signed main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(nullptr);
    solve();
}

